# How I can resolve this : Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `%s`

Tags: react-native, expo

I am new to react-native and this is not me who program this app.

Could someone help me to fix this error, I think  its the flatlist who cause this because it happen only I load the page or search something on the list. I know there is  a lot a question about this error but I don't find a solution for me.

`Warning: Encountered two children with the same key,`%s`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates.`

ContactScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, FlatList, Alert, StyleSheet, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem, SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { Contacts } from 'expo';
import * as Api from '../rest/api';
import theme from '../styles/theme.style';
import { Contact, ContactType } from '../models/Contact';

class ContactsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerTitle: "Contacts",
      headerRight: (
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigation.popToTop()}
          title="Déconnexion"
        />
      ),
    }
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      contacts: [],
      search: '',
      isFetching: false,
      display_contacts: []
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.getContactsAsync();
  }

  async getContactsAsync() {
    const permission = await Expo.Permissions.askAsync(Expo.Permissions.CONTACTS);
    if (permission.status !== 'granted') { return; }

    const contacts = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
        fields: [
          Contacts.PHONE_NUMBERS,
          Contacts.EMAILS,
          Contacts.IMAGE
        ],
        pageSize: 100,
        pageOffset: 0,
    });


    const listContacts = [];
    if (contacts.total > 0) {
      for(var i in contacts.data) {
        let contact = contacts.data[i];
        let id = contact.id;
        let first_name = contact.firstName;
        let middle_name = contact.middleName;
        let last_name = contact.lastName;
        let email = "";
        if ("emails" in  contact && contact.emails.length > 0) {
          email = contact.emails[0].email;
        }
        let phone = "";
        if ("phoneNumbers" in contact && contact.phoneNumbers.length > 0) {
          phone = contact.phoneNumbers[0].number;
        }
        listContacts.push(new Contact(id, first_name, middle_name, last_name, email, phone, ContactType.UP));
      }
    }

    const soemanContacts = await Api.getContacts();
    if (soemanContacts.length > 0) {
      for(var i in soemanContacts) {
        let contact = soemanContacts[i];
        let id = contact.contact_id.toString();
        let first_name = contact.contact_first_name
        let last_name = contact.contact_last_name;
        let email = contact.contact_email;
        let phone = contact.contact_phone.toString();
        listContacts.push(new Contact(id, first_name, "", last_name, email, phone, ContactType.DOWN));
      }
    }

    listContacts.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
    this.setState({contacts: listContacts});
    this.setState({ isFetching: false });
    this.updateSearch(null);
  }

  async addContactAsync(c) {
    const contact = {
      [Contacts.Fields.FirstName]: c.firstName,
      [Contacts.Fields.LastName]: c.lastName,
      [Contacts.Fields.phoneNumbers]: [
        {
          'number': c.phone
        },
      ], 
      [Contacts.Fields.Emails]: [
        {
          'email': c.email
        }
      ]
    }
    const contactId = await Contacts.addContactAsync(contact);
  }

  onRefresh() {
    this.setState({ isFetching: true }, function() { this.getContactsAsync() });
  }

  updateSearch = search => {
    this.setState({ search });
    if(!search) {
      this.setState({display_contacts: this.state.contacts});
    }
    else {

      const res = this.state.contacts.filter(contact => contact.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()));
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({display_contacts: res});
      console.log("contact display "+ this.state.display_contacts);
    }
  };

  toggleContact(contact) {
    switch(contact.type) {
      case ContactType.SYNC:
        break;
      case ContactType.DOWN:
        this.addContactAsync(contact);
        break;
      case ContactType.UP:
        Api.addContact(contact);
        break;
    }
    /*Alert.alert(
      'Synchronisé',
      contact.name + 'est déjà synchronisé'
    );*/
  }

  renderSeparator = () => (
    <View style={{ height: 0.5, backgroundColor: 'grey', marginLeft: 0 }} />
  )

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end' }} behavior="padding" enabled>
        <SearchBar
          platform="default"
          lightTheme={true}
          containerStyle={styles.searchBar}
          inputStyle={styles.textInput}
          placeholder="Type Here..."
          onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
          value={this.state.search}
          clearIcon
        />
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.display_contacts}
          onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()}
          refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={contact => contact.id}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListEmptyComponent={this.renderEmptyContainer()}
        />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderItem = (item) => {
    const contact = item.item;
    let icon_name = '';
    let icon_color = 'black';
    switch(contact.type) {
      case ContactType.SYNC:
        icon_name = 'ios-done-all';
        icon_color = 'green';
        break;
      case ContactType.DOWN:
        icon_name = 'ios-arrow-down';
        break;
      case ContactType.UP:
        icon_name = 'ios-arrow-up';
        break;
    }
    return (
      <ListItem
        onPress={ () => this.toggleContact(contact) }
        roundAvatar
        title={contact.name}
        subtitle={contact.phone}
        //avatar={{ uri: item.avatar }}
        containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
        rightIcon={<Ionicons name={icon_name} size={20} color={icon_color}/>}
      />
    );
  }

  renderEmptyContainer() {
    return (
      <View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  searchBar: {
    backgroundColor: theme.PRIMARY_COLOR
  },
  textInput: {
    backgroundColor: theme.PRIMARY_COLOR,
    color: 'white'
  }
});

export default ContactsScreen;
```

I use react-native and expo for this application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't build keys using the index on the fly. If you want to build keys, you should do it BEFORE render if possible.

If your contacts have a guaranteed unique id, you should use that. If they do not, you should build a key before your data is in the view using a function that produces unique keys

Example code:

```
  // Math.random should be unique because of its seeding algorithm.
  // Convert it to base 36 (numbers + letters), and grab the first 9 characters
  // after the decimal.
  const keyGenerator = () => '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)
  // in component
  key={contact.key}
```

Comment: people like you have bought their way into heaven. please let Saint Peter know you have served your time in hell. thank you for your mastery of key generation God.

Comment: Hi i have this : `const [categories, setCategories] = useState(['One Punch', 'Samurai X', 'Dragon Ball'])`

and in the map: `return <li key={ category }> {category} </li>`

Im new in react how to apply that code above "keyGenerator" to my code?

Answer (score 47):

Just do this in you flatlist

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
```

Comment: Hello, I got the same error, but this solution doesn't work for me. Any solution

Comment: Simply by adding this line (Fast Refresh) nothing happened but after reload the app this worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

I think that your some of contact.id's are same. So you can get this warning. If you set the index number of the list in FlatList, you can't show this.

```
keyExtractor={(contact, index) => String(index)}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do this in your Flatlist

```
 keyExtractor={(id) => { id.toString(); }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same error and I fixed in this case:

do not code in this way (using `async`) - this will repeat render many times per item (I don't know why)

```
Stub_Func = async () => {
  const status = await Ask_Permission(...);
  if(status) {
    const result = await Get_Result(...);
    this.setState({data: result});
  }
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.Stub_Func();
}
```

try something like this (using `then`):

```
Stub_Func = () => {
  Ask_Permission(...).then(status=> {
    if(status) {
      Get_Result(...).then(result=> {
        this.setState({data:result});
      }).catch(err => {
        throw(err);
      });
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    throw(err)
  });
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.Stub_Func();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar warning when using FlatList, despite having the keyExtractor prop configured correctly. I discovered the warning was caused by ListEmptyComponent

To solve it, I added "key" for the component rendered when list is empty, as follow

```js
ListEmptyComponent = {(index) => <Text key={index}>List is Empty</Text>}
```